# passing parameter from php table row

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to pass a name_id parameter through the href via a row in a php table?

`Sample Code`:

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $con = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' ");

    echo "<table class='table table-condensed'>
            <tr>
                <th> name id </th>
                <th> name </th>
                <th> link </th>
            </tr>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<a href='name.php?name_id=$name_id'>view</a>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Eg. Multiple names with an auto incremented id is in the table and I would like it to open the name.php page where I can GET the name_id from the url?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman it's not for a serious website, just a self-taught hobby but thanks - will look into this.

Comment: Just be careful. Even a toy site can get cracked open and cause you hours if not days of trouble.

Comment: oh dear, thanks @tadman best look into it sooner rather than later.

Comment: is the status of this question solved or still open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
  echo "<td>" . "<a href='name.php?name_id=" . $row['name_id'] ."'>". $row['name_id'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will be the simplest solution

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href='name.php?name_id=" . $row['name_id'] . "'>view</a>" . "</td>";
```

Comment: @AliceB1 Edited my answer, missed one quotation mark